# Scraping data from infinite scrolling page using scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm new to web scraping and I want to scrape the information of all the products from a website.

https://www.trendyol.com/

I've written a sample code to scrape data which goes as:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-deterjani-x-c108713',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/yumusaticilar-x-c103814',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-suyu-x-c103812',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-leke-cikaricilar-x-c103810',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-yan-urun-x-c105534',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/kirec-onleyici-x-c103806',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/makine-kirec-onleyici-ve-temizleyici-x-c144512'
        


       
    ]
    

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta, dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    data = re.search(r"__SEARCH_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?});", response.text)
    data = json.loads(data.group(1))
    
    for p in data["products"]:
        item=TeknosaItem()

        item['rowid'] = hash(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + str(p["id"]))
        item['date'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        item['listing_id'] = p["id"]
        item['product_id'] = p["id"]
        item['product_name'] = p["name"]
        item['price'] = p["price"]["sellingPrice"]
        item['url'] = p["url"]
        yield item
```

The code I've written is able to scrape in data for all the products that are listed on first page but as we scroll down the page the page loads more data dynamically via Ajax GET requests and it is not able to scrape that data. I've watched some of the videos and read some articles to but I was not able to figure out how can I scroll data that is being generated dynamically on scrolling. Any help on this will be appreciated.

I found infinite page example on target site:

[web site link](https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-searchgw-service/v2/api/infinite-scroll/camasir-yikama-urunleri-x-c103809?pi=9&culture=tr-TR&userGenderId=1&pId=0&scoringAlgorithmId=2&categoryRelevancyEnabled=false&isLegalRequirementConfirmed=false&searchStrategyType=DEFAULT&productStampType=TypeA&fixSlotProductAdsIncluded=false)

Comment: https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-searchgw-service/v2/api/infinite-scroll/camasir-deterjani-x-c108713?pi=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Scrapy, buy you can adjust next example how to get all products from the category (using their Ajax API):

```py
import requests

categories = [
    "camasir-deterjani-x-c108713",
    "yumusaticilar-x-c103814",
    "camasir-suyu-x-c103812",
    "camasir-leke-cikaricilar-x-c103810",
    "camasir-yan-urun-x-c105534",
    "kirec-onleyici-x-c103806",
    "makine-kirec-onleyici-ve-temizleyici-x-c144512",
]

# iterate over categories to construct api_url
# here I will only get products from first category:
api_url = (
    "https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-searchgw-service/v2/api/infinite-scroll/"
    + categories[0]
)

payload = {
    "pi": 1,
    "culture": "tr-TR",
    "userGenderId": "1",
    "pId": "0",
    "scoringAlgorithmId": "2",
    "categoryRelevancyEnabled": "false",
    "isLegalRequirementConfirmed": "false",
    "searchStrategyType": "DEFAULT",
    "productStampType": "TypeA",
    "fixSlotProductAdsIncluded": "false",
}

page = 1
while True:
    payload["pi"] = page
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=payload).json()

    if not data["result"]["products"]:
        break

    for p in data["result"]["products"]:
        name = p["name"]
        id_ = p["id"]
        price = p["price"]["sellingPrice"]
        u = p["url"]
        print("{:<10} {:<50} {:<10} {}".format(id_, name[:49], price, u[:60]))

    page += 1
```

This will get all products from the category:

```
...

237119563  Organik Sertifikalı Çamaşır Deterjanı              63         /eya-clean/organik-sertifikali-camasir-deterjani-p-237119563
90066873   Toz Deterjan Sık Yıkananlar                        179        /bingo/toz-deterjan-sik-yikananlar-p-90066873
89751820   Sıvı Çamaşır Deterjanı 2 x3L (100 Yıkama) Renkli   144.9      /perwoll/sivi-camasir-deterjani-2-x3l-100-yikama-renkli-siya
112627101  Sıvı Çamaşır Deterjanı (95 Yıkama) 3L Renkli + 2,  144.9      /perwoll/sivi-camasir-deterjani-95-yikama-3l-renkli-2-7l-cic
95398460   Toz Çamaşır Deterjanı Active Beyazlar Ve Renklile  180.99     /omo/toz-camasir-deterjani-active-beyazlar-ve-renkliler-10-k

...
```

Answer (score 1):

So honestly I think the best way is to get the info from the API, but I wanted to answer you question about pagination.

So you can see when you scroll that the url changes (`?pi=pagenumber`), so we can loop through the pages, and when we get to a page that doesn't exist (404 status), we'll handle the status code and break from the loop.

```py
import scrapy
import logging
import json
import datetime


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ExampleSpider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-deterjani-x-c108713',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/yumusaticilar-x-c103814',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-suyu-x-c103812',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-leke-cikaricilar-x-c103810',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/camasir-yan-urun-x-c105534',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/kirec-onleyici-x-c103806',
        'https://www.trendyol.com/makine-kirec-onleyici-ve-temizleyici-x-c144512'
    ]

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4}

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, cb_kwargs={'base_url': url, 'page_number': 0}, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response, base_url, page_number):
        # last page
        if response.status == 404:
            logging.log(logging.INFO, f'Finished scraping {base_url}')
            return

        # You don't need to use beautifulsoup, and you can and the regex directly
        all_data = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/javascript"]/text()').re(r'__SEARCH_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?});')

        for data in all_data:   # supposed to be only one element, but still...
            data = json.loads(data)

            for p in data["products"]:
                # item=TeknosaItem()
                item = dict()
                item['rowid'] = hash(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + str(p["id"]))
                item['date'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                item['listing_id'] = p["id"]
                item['product_id'] = p["id"]
                item['product_name'] = p["name"]
                item['price'] = p["price"]["sellingPrice"]
                item['url'] = p["url"]
                yield item

        # go to the next page
        page_number += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=base_url+f'?pi={str(page_number)}', cb_kwargs={'base_url': base_url, 'page_number': page_number}, callback=self.parse_page)
```